# Google Play android package name changed

Tags: android, google-play, package-name

When I first uploaded a package I used a package name called, "com.sitemane.app"

now I changed the package name to "net.devname.app"

google play wont accept..

it also says I have different finger print.

"You must use the same certificate. Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s):"

what is this?

I need answers for the following 2 questions.

1: can I change the packge name and use it for the same app?

2: what file stores the signatures?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

1. I have not been able to change any package names in Android or BB markets. You will probably have to make a new one and possibly update the old package to have a splash screen to the new one? if it matters that much?
2. I sign all my apps with the same keystore or .keystore I generated. Save this and keep it safe.

http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Answer (score 0):

1. No, on Google Play [you cannot](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#package):

   > Caution: Once you publish your application, you cannot change the package name. The package name defines your application's identity, so if you change it, then it is considered to be a different application and users of the previous version cannot update to the new version.

   You have to create a new one if you want to change your package name.
2. You need to generate it and [save it securely](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#secure-key) for later use. See here for [instructions](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#cert).

Also, there is a [wonderful blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html) about things that cannot change once you register/release your app on Google Play.